# Break jQuery method chain with plguin function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

What I want to achieve is to build a plugin that do some ***validation logic*** on an element, but I want to go on with the next chain methods, but If its not okay, to stop and abort the next chains.

For example, I have this

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = 'check';

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
      }
    });
  }

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    // Do the logic here
  }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

So in order to continue the chain after your callback you must return **this**, as I did in the plugin above.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

button.check().on( 'click', function(){
    // do something
});});
```

But what If I want to execute **click** function only if the **check** function logic condition was met.

Comment: Are you trying to disable events that could be attached to elements following call to plugin?

Comment: You really can't break the chain. You would need conditional logic either before applying the click listener or inside the click handler. Could use a `data()` property to do either perhaps. Not really clear what conditions would be

Comment: @guest271314 Yes.

Comment: @charlietfl
I thought so :( damn...I was hoping on some solution :S

Comment: Can't you assign the click handler inside the plugin? Hard to help without understanding more of the higher level problem

Comment: @charlietfl I took **click** as an example. It can be submit, or anything that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a plain object use `Object.freeze()` to prevent properties of object from being changed; assign object to `$._data(this[0]).events` within plugin to not permit writing `"events"` property at element `$._data()` object.

```js
;
(function($) {
  $.fn.check = function(type, conditions) {
    const el = this;
    let condition = conditions || el[0].tagName === "DIV";
    // if element `.tagName` is `"DIV"` do not set events
    if (condition && !type) {
      if (!$._data(el[0])["events"]) {
        let e = Object.defineProperty(new Object(), "events", {
          value: null
        });
        Object.freeze(e);
        $._data(el[0]).events = e

        return el
      }
    }
    if (type && type === "bool") {
      return condition
    }
    if (type && type === "delete") {
      $._data(el[0]).events = null;
      return this
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
$(function() {
  console.log("check called, do not attach events, try clicking DIV");
  $("div").check().on("click", function(e) {
      console.log(this)
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(e) {
      console.log(this)
    });
  // boolean 
  console.log("check boolean:", $("div").check("bool"));
  console.log("allow events in ten seconds");
  setTimeout(function() {
  // delete 
  console.log("check delete:", $("div").check("delete")[0].tagName);
  console.log("click DIV");
  $("div").on("click", function(e) {
     console.log(this)
  });
  }, 10000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>click</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really apreciate this. But I don't understand quite well. Can you show me specifically the part where you decide whether the chain continues, or don't.

Comment: @ArgircoPopov Still some issues with approach. That is, how to undo current setting at stacksnippets. Current set to `Object.prototype`, though that should probably be changed. The `if` condition that checks `.tagName` of element is part where object that is not writable is assigned to `$._data()` of element.

Comment: I think I got it !! Let me try the whole thing.

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way for me to check if there are attached more chain functions after **check()** ? For example `$('.test').check().on( 'click', function(){});` or it is only the check `$('.test').check()`

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Current approach does not allow events to be set at all after calling `.check()` if condition is not met, due to setting `writable` to `false`

Comment: The idea is that I want to return **true/false** if there are no chain functions after `.check()` and in the other case, if there are I want to block the chain functions after `.check()`

Comment: The thing is that I want to use same function for the both scenarios. I want to use it in this case for example `if( $('.test').check() ) { // do stuff }`, this is the way true/false, And the other case is the one you explain me in the answer, to block the events after it. And yeah, I want to undo events, because this is a kind of validation, and if Is not valid I block the events, and if It is valid we let the events to go.

Comment: You can pass a parameter to `.check()` to determine if `this` or `Boolean` should be returned. If `Boolean` is returned, cannot chain jQuery methods.

Comment: @ArgircoPopov See updated post. Logic may require some adjustments to meet your specific requirements.